# Trying to either pull or recreate trendline data using LINEST

Tags: excel

I am trying to recreate the formula from a trendline on a graph. basically my company is trying to predict the corn yields for next year. all of the actual programmers are out for the week so they passed it on to me(web developer:D). Ive attempted the LINEST formula multiple times with no luck.

basically in column B I have the years(1-15, trying to project 16) and Column C i have the actual trend data. i am probably doing this wrong however

EX `=LINEST(C16:C30,B16:B30,FALSE,FALSE)`

Any help would be appreciated. just tell me if you need the actual file or more information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you aware that `LINEST` returns an **array** of data? This means that you need to select multiple cells for the formula and use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to apply the array formula across all those cells.  Note if you just want the linear trend, you can also use `SLOPE` and `INTERCEPT` to get those pieces.  And if the goal of all this is to use the formula for a forecast, you can use... `FORECAST` (or `TREND`)

Answer (score 0):

The fourth argument, concerning the return of additional regression statistics, is optional and is taken as FALSE if omitted, so seems not required for your purposes. The third argument, concerning the intercept with the Y-axis (the value of **y** when **x** is `0`), is also optional but taken as TRUE if omitted. In your case TRUE seems appropriate so the third parameter seems not required for your purposes.

With your data spanning 15 years, if ending with the current year, it is conveniently 2001-2015 bdi and has no information about the value of **y** (production) in year 2000 (ie when **x** is `0`) but this is unlikely to have been `0`, as would be taken to be the case if the third argument is FALSE.

In a simplified example, take production of `50` in 2001, increasing by an (unrealistically!) constant `5` each year. By 2015 this has reached `120`, so for 2016 *at the same rate of increase* production of `125` should be expected. Your formula returns `9.35` so would predict production of `129.35`, though we know to expect `125`, as given by:

```
=LINEST(C16:C30,B16:B30)
```

when added to the latest available (`120`).

The former is too high a predicted increase because it assumes growth was from `0` to `120` in sixteen years, rather than what I have taken to be from `50` to `120` in fifteen.

As has been mentioned by @Byron Wall, Excel has the [TREND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TREND-function-e2f135f0-8827-4096-9873-9a7cf7b51ef1) function that may be used for linear extrapolation to obtain the next (16th) value like so:

```
=TREND(C16:C30,B16:B30,16)
```

This directly returns `125` for the, simplified, sample data.

HOWEVER, all the above assumes growth is linear. Taking say Brazilian corn production (Million tons) over the period (offset one year) this has been roughly (based on [USDA.gov](http://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/chart-gallery/detail.aspx?chartId=44458)):

[image: SO31321385 first example]

The red line is the Linear trend and green a fourth order Polynomial. They happen both to end up at the same place for one year ahead (the hollow bar) but predict different results from the latest six years:

[image: SO31321385 second example]

It may be worth charting the data you have, and adding different trend lines, before deciding whether linear extrapolation seems the most promising for forecasting purposes. ‘Wavy’ (cyclical) progress is evident in many datasets.